# how to check if stored procedure exists or not in sql server using c# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried below code for cheking SP is alredy exist or not. if not exist i am creating..

But every time it is showing sp is not created.....But my database already have this sp.

Let me know where i am doing mistake.

```
string checkSP = String.Format(
  "IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 'true' ELSE SELECT 'false'", 
  "GP_SOP_AdjustTax");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(checkSP, myConnection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

if (myConnection == null || myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + a.Message);
    }
}

bool Exist = false;
Exist = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteScalar());
if (Exist == false)   //false : SP does not exist
{ 
    // here i am writing code for creating SP
}
```

Comment: There are some system views that should be accessible, just place a query on them to see if you have SPs or a specific SP. I can't remember the name of the system view/table but it's easy to find in the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
if exists(select * from sys.objects where type = 'p' and name = '<procedure name>' )
```

Also you can check that with c#:

```
string connString = "";
string query = "select * from sysobjects where type='P' and name='MyStoredProcedureName'";
bool spExists = false;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                spExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing the reader.Read() in a while loop ? wouldnt it be sufficient to have an if check?

Comment: If you really are going to bring back more than 1 row, then you should put it in a while loop. and If you expect only 0 or 1 rows, you can have if check

Comment: ...or just use `select top 1 ....`; that will ensure you will always get 0 (does not exist) or 1 (exists) row.

Comment: This isn't schema aware, you will get false positives with procedures with the same name and different schemas. For example dbo.MyStoredProcedureName, and SomeSchema.MyStoredProcedureName. It also doesn't normalise the names, so [MyStoredProcedureName] doesn't return any results. The answer by Jakub Konecki below deals with both these cases.

Answer (score 7):

> **For those who use Entity Framework and a DbContext:**

create an extension class for DbContext:

```
internal static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static bool StoredProcedureExists(this DbContext context,
        string procedureName)
    {
        string query = String.Format(
            @"select top 1 from sys.procedures " +
              "where [type_desc] = '{0}'", procedureName);
        return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).Any();
    }
}
```

As robIII remarked, this code should not be published to the outside world as it makes the database vulnerable for hackers (thank you RobIII!). To prevent this use a parameterized statement. [The problem with the above mentioned method is described here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

The solution is to put procedureName **as a parameter** in an SQL statement. SQL will check if the string parameter has the desired format, thus inhibiting malicious calls:

```
public static bool ImprovedExists(this DbContext dbContext, string procedureName)
{
    object[] functionParameters = new object[]
    {
        new SqlParameter(@"procedurename", procedureName),
    };
    const string query = @"select [name] from sys.procedures where name= @procedurename";
    return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, functionParameters).Any();
}
```

Comment: [Could you check if the stored procedure "`'; drop table users; --`" exists?](https://xkcd.com/327/) ;-) Use [parameterized statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Answer (score 5):

I found this on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/eb986342-af36-488e-9c5b-8ea8e2ca6c1e)

```
select * from sys.objects where type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' AND name = 'Sql_PersonInsert'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'GP_SOP_AdjustTax') AND type in (N'P', N'PC')
```

Answer (score 3):

My stab at it:

- Reusable extension method
- Minimal Sql / Minimal C#
- Called from .Net as the OP implicitly requested
- Could be faster because of the `object_id` function

```cs
public static bool StoredProcedureExists(this string source)
{
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
  {
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand($"select object_id('{source}')", conn))
      return !cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString().IsNullOrWhiteSpace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check with following tsql query (suitable for SQL Server):

```
select * from sysobjects where ytype='P' and name='MyStoredProcedureName'
```

If query returns row then stored procedure named 'MyStoredProcedureName' exists.

And here is how you can use it in code:

```
        //TODO: set connection string
        string connString = "";
        string query = "select * from sysobjects where ytype='P' and name='MyStoredProcedureName'";
        bool spExists = false;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        spExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string checkSP = String.Format(
  "IF OBJECT_ID('{0}', 'U') IS NOT NULL SELECT 'true' ELSE SELECT 'false'", 
  "GP_SOP_AdjustTax");
```

is fine if you change the 'U' to 'P'.
With 'U' you query for user-tables, where 'P' gives you stored-procedures.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static bool StoredProcedureExists(string sp)
{    
      var connString = @"<your string here>";
      var query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(0) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = '{0}'", sp);
      using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
      {
          conn.Open();
          using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
          {
              return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;  
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Handles procedure names with different schemas
- Names with and without brackets ([])
- Uses parameter to avoid SQL injection

Note: Caller owns SQL Connection

```
public static class SqlConnectionExtensions
{        
    public static Task<bool> StoredProcedureExistsAsync(this SqlConnection sqlConnection, string storedProcedureName)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@storedProcedureName) AND type in (N'P', N'PC')";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@storedProcedureName", storedProcedureName);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return reader.ReadAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works with MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle I think:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
AND (ROUTINE_SCHEMA='questionnaire' OR ROUTINE_CATALOG = 'questionnaire')
AND SPECIFIC_NAME='create_question';
```

Usage:

```
string procedureName = "create_question";
using (DbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=questionnaire;Trusted_Connection=True;")) // Connection is interchangeable
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE' AND (ROUTINE_SCHEMA='{conn.Database}' OR ROUTINE_CATALOG = '{conn.Database}') AND SPECIFIC_NAME='{procedureName}';";
        return cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`, try

```
private static bool CheckIfStoredProcedureExists(Database db, string spName, string schema)
{
   db.StoredProcedures.Refresh();
   return (db.StoredProcedures[spName, schema] != null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
if object_id('YourStoredProcedureName') is null
    exec ('create procedure dbo.YourSp as select 1')
go
alter procedure dbo.YourStoredProcedure
as
```